# jquery to add ids to all paras to make them all linkable.

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have a site with thousands of htm documents on them. Sometimes I need to send someone to a specific paragraph to read. 
What I am looking for is a jquery plugin which simply adds ids to all the paragraphs, making them linkable, so we could send them to: http://www.demo.com/index.html#p_10 for instance.

Comment: You can use jquery each to add attributes but the problem will be that it will add the attributes after the url is read.

Comment: And why would that be a problem?

Comment: Why a plugin? I would suggest writing a small snippet that loops over the required `p` elements and adds an `id` attribute to them.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is just a simple code like this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('p').each(function(index, value) {
        value.id = '_p' + index;
    });

    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(window.location.hash).offset().top
    }, 500);
});
```

Here is an example that also displays the id set.

http://jsfiddle.net/ekftprLt/2/

Comment: Which will not actually GO to the P

Comment: Will if you use an anchor

Comment: You're right, it won't scroll unless you click on the browser URL field and press enter. Added a scroll animation to scroll to the paragraph, thank you for your comment.

Comment: Brilliant, does the job perfectly, thank you Pedro and everyone else so much.

Comment: Please see my update which does not modify the DOM and would be WAY faster than the above

Answer (score 1):

Why a plugin? And no need for an ID

This should work if you insert a script into the page or into an existing external script

**NOTE:** This does NOT modify the DOM in any way and is WAY faster than an .each

```
$(function() {
  var pIndexPos = location.hash.indexOf("p_");
  if (pIndexPos!=-1) {
    var pIndex = parseInt(location.hash.substring(pIndexPos+2),10)+1; // 1based for nth
    var offsetTop = $("p:nth-child("+pIndex+")").offset().top-20; // - height of item
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: offsetTop
    },500);
  }
});
```

Comment: Dear mplungjan, thanks for the reply, and I'm sure this will be the answer for someone, but for myself I need to see exactly where to direct someone, so I do in fact need the ID.

Comment: What will make the IDs visible to you? Unless you insert §1, §2 or something into the HTML of each paragraph, there will be no difference on the page.

Comment: Hi mplungjan, I can easily inspect the element and grab the ID, which saves me counting paras, etc.

Comment: Whatever floats your boat