# jquery animation scrollTop dont work in ie or firefox

Tags: jquery

A simple scroll to top effect...The code doesn't work in ie or firefox but works fine in chrome.

**html like this** :

```
<a href="#"  class="scrollTop"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></i></a>
```

**And script like this** :

```
$(document.body).animate({
   'scrollTop':'0'
},2000);
```

I have tried to replace`$(document.body)` with `$("body")`,nothing happen...

Comment: Try unquoting to scrollTop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery .scrollTop(); + animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16475198/jquery-scrolltop-animation)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Animate scrollTop not working in firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8149155/animate-scrolltop-not-working-in-firefox)

Comment: If you follow the solution presented in that duplicate, it will work: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/oesf4tz5/2/

Answer (score 1):

I posted a similar answer on this post:

[jquery to add ids to all paras to make them all linkable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954706/jquery-to-add-ids-to-all-paras-to-make-them-all-linkable/26954753?noredirect=1#comment42450963_26954753)

I tested the following code on Firefox and IE 10 and works fine.

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop : 0
}, 500);
```